# Stop a symbol on the navigation path

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, json, google-maps-api-3

In this project, there are symbols for navigation path of research project ships.

The ships go along a navigation route. The start and end points come from the database.
The Code to initialise the start and end points.

```
<?php
    $sqlqry = "SELECT * FROM ship WHERE id=" . $id . " AND start_date BETWEEN '" . $s_date . "' AND '" . $e_date . "'";
    $result = mysqli_query($bd, $sqlqry);
    $locations = array();
    $counter=0;
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
        array_push($locations, $row);
    }
    $nrows = mysqli_num_rows($result);
?>
```

The ships should halt at a median point (Mother ship) which is static.
The problem is that the ships go continuously and do not stop at the median point.

Code to initialise the median point or the mother ship.

```
<?php
    $result = mysqli_query($bd,"SELECT * FROM mother_ship WHERE id=".$id);
    $m_ship = array();
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
        array_push($m_ship, $row);
    }
    $m_ship_rows = mysqli_num_rows($result);
?>
```

This is my code segment for the navigation of the ships using Google Maps API in JavaScript.

```
//Initialization Of Data From DB
    var nrows = <?php echo json_encode($nrows,JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK);?>;
    var locMatrix = <?php echo json_encode($locations,JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK);?>;
    var m_ship_rows = <?php echo json_encode($m_ship_rows,JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK);?>;
    var m_ship = <?php echo json_encode($m_ship,JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK);?>;

      var line;
      var line1;
      var lineArray = [];
      var lineArray1 = [];
      var DrivePath = [];
      // This example adds an animated symbol to a polyline.

      function initMap() {

        var intervalForAnimation;
        var count = 0;
        var n = 2;

        for(var i=0;i<=nrows-1;i++)
        {
        console.log(DrivePath[i]);
        DrivePath.push(new google.maps.LatLng(locMatrix[i][0], locMatrix[i][1]),
                  new google.maps.LatLng(17.8674, 66.543),
                  new google.maps.LatLng(locMatrix[i][2], locMatrix[i][3]));
      }
        var Colors = [
        "#FF0000", 
        "#00FF00", 
        "#0000FF", 
        "#FFFFFF", 
        "#000000", 
        "#FFFF00", 
        "#00FFFF", 
        "#FF00FF"
        ];


//Code for navigation path creation.
        for (var i = 0; i < DrivePath.length-1; i++) {
              var line = new google.maps.Polyline({
              path: [DrivePath[i], DrivePath[i+1]],
              icons: [
                {
                  icon: symbolShape,
                  offset: '0%'
                }
              ],
              strokeColor: Colors[i],
              strokeOpacity: 0.0,
              strokeWeight: 2,
              map: map
            });
             lineArray[i] = line;
            }

        for (var i = 0; i < DrivePath.length-1; i++) {
            line1 = new google.maps.Polyline({
              path: [DrivePath[i], DrivePath[i+1]],
              icons: [
                {
                  icon: symbolSource,
                  offset: '0%'
                }, {
                  icon: symbolDestination,
                  offset: '100%'
                }
              ],
              strokeColor: Colors[i],
              strokeOpacity: 1.0,
              strokeWeight: 2,
              map: map
            });
            lineArray1[i] = line1;
          }

            console.log(lineArray.length);
            console.log(lineArray1.length);

          //Map boundaries
          var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
            for (var i = 0; i < line.getPath().getLength(); i++) {
              bounds.extend(line.getPath().getAt(i));
            }
          map.fitBounds(bounds);

      // Use the DOM setInterval() function to change the offset of the symbol
      // at fixed intervals.
      function animateCircle(count) {
        for(var i = 0; i < lineArray.length; i++){
          line10 = lineArray[i];
          var icons = line10.get('icons');
          icons[0].offset = (count / 2) + '%';
          line10.set('icons', icons);
          $("#slider").slider("value", count);
          }
          if (count >= 199){ 
            clearInterval(intervalForAnimation);
            clearTheLines();
            motherShipLayer.setMap(null);
          };    
      }

        function clearTheLines(){
            for(var i = 0; i < lineArray1.length; i++){
              line11 = lineArray1[i];
              line11.setMap(null);
            }
        }
```

Also, I would like to note that I have a slider associated with the navigation path that will help in playing pausing and resetting the navigation path.

[As you can see here, the mother ship is in the centre and there are two ships. The problem is that the ship just comes and goes.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j4Xyw.png)

The Google Maps JavaScript Code is at [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/9tcoL9b3/)

Also if you are interested, the project is at

http://github.com/Tejas-Nanaware/ship-scheduling-and-animation-tool